# Change position according to the scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, position

I would like to change the position according to my scroll.
And because pictures speak a thousand words, here's what I want :

[image]

And here's my code : **https://jsfiddle.net/njz87Lth/1/**

html :

```
<h1> MY TEXT. orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </h1>
<div class="one"> </div>
<div class="two"> </div>
```

css :

```
body {
  text-align:center;
}

h1 {
  left: 0;
  line-height:2;
  right:0;
  width:600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position:fixed;
}

.one, .two {
  width:600px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.one {
    top:100px;
    height:300px;
    background:grey;
}

.two {
    height:800px;
    background:pink;
    margin-top:30px;
    top:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
     $(".one").offset({ left: left, top: top});

});
```

give `offset` values according to your need.